# Bulk export all leads as JSON format in marketo

Tags: marketo

I need to bulk export all the leads using Rest API in JSON format. There is an option only to export the data in CSV file. But I need to get the data in RAW JSON format. Is it possible marketo.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk export file type options are only TSV (tab) and CSV (comma). The only option for you would be converting one of those files to JSON - which should be simple enough since it's flat, tabular data.